# Piskei Teshuvos on sleeping before Shacharis if one was up all night

Tags: halacha, tefilla

Halachipedia says that Piskei Teshuvos 89:22 and Ishei Yisrael 13:31 rule that one may not go to sleep within half an hour of alos hashachar if one was up all night before davening Shacharis.  Can someone who has access to the Piskei Teshuvos and/or Ishei Yisrael copy and paste what they say in those places in the original Hebrew?   Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. I'm not sure if this question is on topic since it is ostensibly about Judaism, but the question is really only asking for someone to type/paste a series of characters.

Comment: We have had some questions like this in the past. does anyone know if there was ever a Meta discussion about it? [This one](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4720/are-questions-of-the-form-rabbi-so-and-so-wrote-a-sefer-on-x-jewish-topic-but) is somewhat related.

Comment: Try https://www.hebrewbooks.org/1757 for פסקי תשובה

Comment: There are way too many books called אשי ישראל and none of them seem relevant.

Comment: @DannySchoemann that's piskei teshuva he wants piskei teshuvos which is on the Mishnah Berurah. Ishei Yisroel is a contemporary sefer on tefillah with halachos from Rav Chaim Kanievsky. Neither are freely available online

Answer (score 1):

פסקי תשובות אורח חיים סימן פט
כב. שינה סמוך לעלות השחר או לאחריה

שם: דבתוך חצי שעה אסור להתחיל לאכול וכו' וה"ה לגבי ק"ש דאורייתא. ובסימן רל"ה (סקי"ז) כתב המשנ"ב עפ"י הגמרא כמו כן לענין שינה שאסור לישן חצי שעה קודם זמן ק"ש של ערבית שמא ימשך בשינתו ויפסיד המצוה, וכן כתב בסי' תרצ"ב (סקט"ו) לענין קריאת מגילה. ויש שכתבו שהוא הדין ממש לנידוננו למי שהיה ער כל הלילה שאסור לו לילך לישן כשכבר חצי שעה קודם עלות השחר, וכל שכן לאחר שעלה עמוד השחר, עד שיקרא קריאת שמע ויתפלל.

אמנם בעוד שלענין ק"ש של ערבית הדגישו כמה פוסקים שאין מועיל העמדת שומר, כי ערבך ערבא צריך ושמא גם השומר ישקע בשינה, לעניננו יועיל העמדת השומר (שכבר ישן בלילה) שיעירנו בזמן שיספיק לקרוא ק"ש ולהתפלל בעוד שלא עבר הזמן, וכך נכון לעשות למי שראשו כבד עליו וזקוק לשינה כדי שיוכל להתפלל בכוונה ובצלילות הדעת.

ואם ישן בלילה אלא שהתעורר לאחר עלות השחר וברצונו להמשיך לישן, רשאי ואין בזה חשש, דלא חששו לאונס שינה אלא כשלא ישן כל הלילה, אמנם הכל לפי מה שהוא אדם לפי טבעו, ואם עלול לימשך בשינה עד לאחר זמן ק"ש אף שישן כמה שעות בלילה ודאי צריך להעמיד שומר או שעון מעורר שיעירנו.